# How do I configure front page?

Tags: 7

I have a new installation and I have "No front page content has been created yet".  How do I configure this front page?  How do I give a new user the ability to create their own blogs whilst also preventing them from having full control of the system?

Comment: The question as it's asked now is a little bit too broad. Everything you want to know is pretty well documented on https://drupal.org

Answer (score 1):

### Build Your Own Content Type

Create a Blog Content Type:

- Admin > Structure > Content Types > Add Content Type (yoursite.ca/admin/structure/types/add)
- Put "Blog" as the name of the content type
- Adjust the opitions, (Submission form settings, Publishing options, Display settings, Menu settings), accordingly
- Add the fields you want. If you want Tags, you could add a Taxonomy reference field

To allow users to make blogs, but not anything else:

- go to `Admin > People > Permissions` (yoursite.ca/admin/people/permissions)
- scroll down to the **Node** Section
- select permissions, normally *Blog: Create new content* and *Blog: Edit own content* at least, for the role you want, (or AUTHENTICATED USER, which is every logged in user)

### Use Core Content Type

There is already a core content type called article that has the following fields:

- Title
- Body
- Image
- Tags

Instead of making your own content type, you could just use this one.

To allow them to make blogs, but not anything else:

- go to `Admin > People > Permissions` (yoursite.ca/admin/people/permissions)
- scroll down to the **Node** Section
- select permissions, normally *Article*: Create new content* and *Article: Edit own content* at least, for the role you want, (or AUTHENTICATED USER, which is every logged in user)

### Remove front page message

A couple of options. The most elegant is to make a landing page and set that page as the "welcome" page at Admin > Configuration > System > Site information (yoursite.ca/admin/config/system/site-information)

Other options:

- a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_front_page)
- CSS (Set `display: none` on the element)
- A view. Follow these [instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1049290#comment-5804412).
- Or scroll to the top of the mentioned link and read the forum. There are a ton of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a front-page configuration. What you are seeing is the default front page. If you create some nodes (aka content), they will show up on that page automatically. So if you give your users permission to create blogs, the blogs will show up on that page.

As for giving users permission to create blogs, first you need to create a blog content type. Then give authenticated users permission to create blogs.